# iText pageElement placing side by side

Tags: pdf, itext

I am new to iText and i am told to create a PDF with a structure as shown in the picture, I just need some help regarding can one generate a PDF with following structure. If can be achieved please give me links or anything that will help get started on such a PDF generation.

I know how to generate every element in single and place in one after another but i have no idea where to start and place them side by side.

I using iText's 5 version.

[image]

Comment: http://itextpdf.com/book , go to the examples and search for samples using columntext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a double post. The question was already posted and answered on the [iText mailing-list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66289/focus=66290).
As Michaël Demey already indicated, you need to use `ColumnText`. There's an example with a result similar to what you need [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=91). The result is [a PDF with tables that are presented next to each other](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/column_table.pdf). Using the information of chapter 3 and 4 of my book it should be fairly easy to achieve what you want.

I would add the picture at an absolute postion with the ´setAbsolutePostion()´ method. I'd create a `PdfPTable` with all the data, and I'd add this table to a `ColumnText` object. Then I'd render the columns defining different rectangles with the `setSimpleColumn()` method, up until the contents of the column have been completely "consumed".