# Divide one PDF page into two equal section vertically using export plugin or iText: Grails

Tags: grails, pdf-generation, itext, export-to-pdf

I am currently using Export 1.6 plugin for exporting my SQL queried data into PDF in Grails.

I have tiered but not able to find the exact solution for -

> I want to generate dynamically multi page PDF, but the page should be
>   equally partitioned into two equal section vertically.I used document.newPage() but this is dividing a page into two
>   pages.

code snippet-

```
protected void exportData(OutputStream outputStream, List data, List fields) throws ExportingException{
        Rectangle left;
        Rectangle right;
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
        int side_of_the_page = 0;

        ct.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 290, 806);
        int paragraphs = 0;
        while (paragraphs < 30) {
            ct.addElement(new Paragraph(String.format("Paragraph %s: %s", ++paragraphs, TEXT)));
            while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(ct.go())) {
                if (side_of_the_page == 0) {
                    side_of_the_page = 1;
                    canvas.moveTo(297.5f, 36);
                    canvas.lineTo(297.5f, 806);
                    //canvas.colorStroke
                    canvas.stroke();
                }
                else {
                    side_of_the_page = 0;

                    PdfPTable talble =  new PdfPTable()
                    while(data.size())
                    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell()


                    ct.addElement(data);
                    document.newPage();
                }

                ct.setSimpleColumn(305, 36, 559, 806);
            }
        }
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }



}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is a possible duplicate of [iText pageElement placing side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267063/itext-pageelement-placing-side-by-side). If not, please explain why `ColumnText` doesn't solve your problem (assuming that you've actually tried `ColumnText`; we can't tell, you don't show us any code).

Comment: Is there any simple basic example for ColumnText ?                                                   I am not able to split my page into two section getting different different types of error while using ColumnText, please provide any simple example for that. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just made one this morning in answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378407/how-can-you-eliminate-white-space-in-multiple-columns-using-itextsharp

Comment: You mentioned an exception that has my name in it: `No signature of method: com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.setSimpleColumn() is applicable for ...` When I see my name in code or stacktraces, I know that people are using a version of iText that is no longer supported and that should no longer be used (it is almost 6 years old). You shouldn't expect examples that have been written in the last couple of years to work with a version of iText that old. Please upgrade!

Comment: I am using latest Grails export plugin version "export:1.6", but using that I have to do all PDF genration,vertically divide and many layout design and so on. Please help me I am newbie to all these.

Comment: When a  version is not supported, there is no support. That's what unsupported means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **itextpdf-5.x.x.jar** instead of your default Grails export plugin.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```